# Android: Check if fragment exits in Stack and reuse it

Tags: android, android-fragments, stack

Hi I am using a **Stack** variable for storing the sequence of fragments clicked by the user

For example : [A,B,C,A,D]

Now I need to check if a fragment exits in the stack I need to reuse it.
From the above example I need to reuse the first element i.e, A when user clicks on the fourth time.

The problem is I have a custom keyboard opening in fragment A, now if the same fragment is in the stack as forth element the keyboard is not opening .but when I backpress and go to first element keyboard  is opened in the first instance of A

**Code for storing in the Stack**

```
public void switchContent(Fragment fragment) {
    if(mContent !=null && (fragment.getClass().toString().equals(mContent.getClass().toString()))){
        getSlidingMenu().showContent();
        return;
        }

    mContent = fragment;

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.content_frame, mContent);
    FragmentChangeActivity.fragmentStack.lastElement().onPause();
    FragmentChangeActivity.fragmentStack.push(mContent);
    ft.commit();
    getSlidingMenu().showContent();

}
```

**Code for backpress**

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (fragmentStack.size() >= 2) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentStack.lastElement().onPause();
            ft.remove(fragmentStack.pop());
            fragmentStack.lastElement().onResume();
            ft.show(fragmentStack.lastElement());
            ft.commit();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code check's if `Fragment` named SearchFragment exists or not in backstack and processes accordingly. You can use this logic to determine if a specific `Fragment` exists or not

```
        FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment currentFragment = (Fragment)fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.mainContent);
        if(currentFragment!=null && currentFragment instanceof SearchFragment){
            //SearchFragment exists in backstack , process accordingly
        }else{
            //SearchFragment not present in backstack
        }
```